# React design: How can I avoid calling a child component's function from the parent?

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 components: Main.jsx (red), GridControl.jsx (blue), and Grid.jsx (green).

[image]

The purpose of the grid control is to save, undo, and redo edits made to the grid below. Understandably, this depends heavily on a lot of logic and data found in Grid.jsx.

So the easiest thing to do would be to include GridControl in Grid, so that Grid can pass information down to GridControl.

*However*, I really want the grid control buttons to be aligned with the other buttons in Main (the dropdowns and 'get data'), for which it is easier to leave GridControl in Main and try to access the Grid's save, undo and redo logic from there. It does feel like doing so would break React's design patterns though, so I'm really no sure what to do.

Is there a neat way to go about this without putting everything in one component or breaking design patterns? I would really appreciate some help here, looking to learn the 'right way' to go about using React in tricky situations like these. Would calling Grid's functions from Main to pass into GridControl indeed be bad practice?

Here is the return statement I currently have in Main.jsx (this makes it easy to align all the buttons, but I need to find a reliable way to make the grid control work):

```
return (
    <div id='mainpage'>
        <div id='filters-and-grid-controls'>
            <div id='dropdowns'>
                <Dropdown2 value={version} label='Version' options={versions} setter={setVersion} />
                <Dropdown2 value={period} label='Period' options={periods} setter={setPeriod} />
                <button id="get-data" className="button" onClick={handleGetData}>Get Data</button>
            </div>
            <GridControl />
        </div>
        <Grid gridData={gridData} getDataAfterSave={handleSave} />
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a context in your `Main` component something like this:

```
export const MyContext = createContext(null);
// ...
const Main = () => {
 const [data, setData] = useState();
 return (
 <MyContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
    // ...
    <GridControl />
    <Grid />
    // ...
 </MyContext.Provider>
);
}
```

Now since `GridControl` and `Grid` are wrapped within `MyContext.Provider` they can have access to the provided values i.e `data` and `setData` you just have to use the context

```js
import {MyContext} from './main'
const Grid = () => {
const {data, setData} = useContext(MyContext)
// ...
}
```

see [useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext)

Comment: Hmm I could be wrong but I think what I need is the other way around - with Grid being the one having data and Main/GridControl needing to get it from Grid. I.e. passing data/setdata from Grid->Main.

And it seems the only way I can pull the save/undo/redo logic out of Grid is if I pull all of Grid out and put it into Main.

Comment: @WesternCreamCheese you know better what to do you got the idea  but keep in mind that the context should be created on the top level then provided to children

Comment: What are these `data` and `setData` attributes on the context provider? As far as I know you can only provide a `value` attribute. Did you mean to write: `<MyContext.Provider value={{data, setData}}>` or something else?

Comment: @MaksVerver oh my bad thank you for the input, was a typo ^^

Answer (score 1):

Will depend how complex is your logic inside of Grid.

To resume your problem you need pass data between siblings components.

To archive this create the data that you need use in GridControl on the parent component and then pass to Grid and GridControl.

This is a minimal example

```
const Main = () => {
  const [shareData, setShareData] = useState(null);
  // Create other share function here
  // Also you can pass the setShareData and mutate the state down
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid shareData={shareData} setShareData={setShareData}>
        hello
      </Grid shareData={shareData} setShareData={setShareData}>
      <GridControl>hello</GridControl>
    </div>
  );
};

const Grid = ({shareData, setShareData}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>shareData</h1>
      <Button onClick={() => setShareData('hello')}>Click me</Button>
    </div>
  );
};

const GridControl = ({shareData, setShareData}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>shareData</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Other option is use a library to manage global states like [context](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext) or [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started), but I don't recommend that to your case. These are more when you need pass data deeply in your app.